# GET method of URL contains special character

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I've got a javascript script inside a wordpress post that send 4 variables to a URL.

Now, since by default wordpress converts '&' to &#038, the destination url becomes `http://localhost/mysite/add.php?var1=a&#038;var2=b&#038;var3=c&#038;var4=d`

instead of

```
http://localhost/mysite/add.php?var1=a&var2=b&var3=c&var4=d
```

And the php script contained in add.php gets only var1.

Is it possible to fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: What does the code look like that creates this URL?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    function save(){
      var var1=a; 
      var var2=b;
      var var3=c;
      var var4=d;
     window.location.href = "http://localhost/mysite/add.php?var1=" + var1 + "&var2="+var2 + "&var3="+var3 + "&var4="+var4;
    }
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to declare another variable and make the `&` character at runtime:

```
var amp = String.fromCharCode(38);
window.location.href = ... var1 + amp + "var2=" + var2 + amp +...
```

More elegant might be to use [`jQuery.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)